# Laravel: laravel-translatable plugin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I use the laravel (4.2) plugin (https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) and i was wondering if anyone knows how to dynamically adjusts "fallback locale".

I have tried this but still not work:

```
App::make('config')->set('translatable.fallback_locale', 'sl');
```

Thanks for answer!

====

**I have found solution...**

```
Config::set('translatable::fallback_locale', 'sl');
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to change Locale on based on a certain condition?

Comment: @Digitlimit I just found a solution. I updated the question.

Comment: @DanielJaušovec You should answer your own question (as an answer), so that it could be marked resolved.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation here https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable#documentation you can set your fallback locale in your configuration.

```
return [
   'use_fallback' => true,

   'fallback_locale' => 'sl',    
];
```